# How to free Redis Scala client allocated by RedisClientPool?

Tags: scala

I am using debasishg/scala-redis as my Redis Client.
I want it to support multi threaded executions. Following their documentation: https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis I defined

```
val clients = new RedisClientPool("localhost", 6379)
```

and then using it on each access to redis:

```
clients.withClient {
  client => {
    ...
   }
}
```

My question is, do I need to free each allocated client? And if so, what is a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the constructor for [`RedisClientPool`](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis/blob/e46f71239c581df021997f13973846fbab859fa9/src/main/scala/com/redis/Pool.scala), there is a default value `maxIdle` ("the maximum number of objects that can sit idle in the pool", as per [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html)), and a default value for `poolWaitTimeout`. You can change those values, but basically if you wait `poolWaitTimeout` you are guaranteed to have your ressources cleaned, except for the `maxIdle` clients on stand-by.

Also, if you can't stand the idea of `idle clients`, you can shut down the whole pool with `mypool.close`, and create it again when needed, but depending on your use case that might defeat the purpose of using a pool (if it's a cron job I guess that's fine).